# I keep getting Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY: QUERY was empty

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a register page. When I enter the data that needs to be registered, it shows up on the console followed by Error: ER_EMPTY_QUERY.

I believe the problem is in the controllers/auth.js file but I can't figure it out for some reason. Please help, been stuck on this for the past 2 days.

controllers/auth.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs'); 

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'practice'
})

exports.register = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)

    const {name, email, password, passwordConfirm} = req.body

    db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?' [email], async (error, results) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

        if( results.length > 0 ) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'That email is already is use'
            })
        } else if( password !== passwordConfirm) {
          return res.render('register', {
              message: 'Passwords do not match'
          })
        }

        let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
        console.log(hashedPassword);

        db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', {name: name, email: email, password: hashedPassword}, (error, results) => {
            if(error) {
              console.log(error)
            } else {
                console.log(results);
                return res.render('register', {
                    message: 'User registered'
                })
            }
        })


    }) 

  
}
```

register.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <h4>Node MySQL</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/register">register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container mt-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Register Form
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="/auth/register" method="POST">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="email">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="passwordConfirm">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm">
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{#if message}}
        <h4 class="alert alert-daner mt-4">{{message}}</h4>
        {{/if}}


    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is _way_ too much code. Remember to reduce your code down to the absolute smallest [mvcve] first, then put _that_ in your post if that exercise didn't allow you to find out what's wrong on your own (which it almost always does, if you actually take the time to reduce your code to the bare minimum). Also, try to never use "it doesn't work" because that's not a problem description, that's just an opinion in conflict with the code (the code does _exactly_ what you wrote it to do, it is _always_ working exactly as written).

Comment: And remember to read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't yet: it's a pretty important bit of SO policy to have read and understood, so your posts follow those guidelines.

Comment: Ok I've edited the post so it's not mostly code. @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: There are two db queries: which one's triggering the ER_EMPTY_QUERY, and what are the values you're actually putting in? (show those as hard coded `const` rather than pulling them from req.body, because the request is basically irrelevant here, it's the db execution you're interested in) Also note that at this point you should be able to run that server code on its own rather than keeping it an export, without needing an html file.